# Looking for a way to change the stage width in haxeflixel

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

```
function resizegaem4by3(){
        #if desktop
        lime.app.Application.current.window.resize(960, 720);
        lime.app.Application.current.window.x += 160;
        #end
        FlxG.resizeGame(960,720);
        Lib.current.stage.stageWidth = 960; (problem)
    }
```

ive looked through the haxeflixel documentation yet found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
FlxG.resizeWindow(w, h);
```

You may want/need to call

```
Lib.application.window.move(newX, newY);
```

after to position your window.